# Setting image instead of java standard ellipse Java Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a solar system using processing but I'm stuck at trying to set an image instead of using the java standard elipse image.
I started this at school and it consisted of an ellipse rotating around another ellipse.

```
  package processing;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class SolarSystem extends PApplet{
    PImage background;
    Pianets earth;
    public void settings() {
        size(650,500);
    }
    public void setup() {

        background = loadImage("C:\\background\\bg.jpg");
        earth = new Pianets(this, width/2,height/2,40, 200, 0);

    }

    public void draw() {
        background(background);
        earth.showEarth();
        earth.rotateEarth(0.007f);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("processing.SolarSystem");

    }

}
```

Planets class

```
package processing;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Pianets {
    PApplet vis;
    float x0,y0; //centre
    float diam;
    float r; //distance from the centre
    float alpha; //rotation angle

    public Pianeti(PApplet applet, float x, float y, float diam,float r, float alpha){
        vis = applet;
        this.x0=x;
        this.y0=y;
        this.diam=diam;
        this.r=r;
        this.alpha=alpha;
    }

    void rotateEarth(float deltaAlpha){
        alpha +=deltaAlpha;

    }

    void showEarth(){
        //drawing the body of object at the centre
        vis.ellipse(x0, y0, diam, diam);
        float x = x0 + r*vis.cos(alpha);
        float y = y0 + r*vis.sin(alpha);

        vis.ellipse(x,y,diam,diam);
    }
```

I created two images on paint that are the earth and the sun but I don't know how to set the image up.

Comment: Same way your `SolarSystem` class has a PImage, so could your `Pianets` class. Also, try to be consistent and spellcheck your code: it will help you on the long run. (`Pianeti` is not the same as `Pianets`, might as well use `Planet` instead for both class name and constructor)

Comment: The reason there is Pianeti is becouse my code is written in Italian and I translated it to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this are best answered by looking at [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/). There's an **Image** section that lists a `loadImage()` function for loading an image file, and an `image()` function for drawing it. Please read those.

You should also get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). For example, instead of posting your whole project (which has nothing to do with loading images right now), try to create a smaller example program that just shows a single image. Get that working perfectly before moving on. Then if you're confused about something, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on images in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/images.html).